# Store data in the memory instead of JPA

Tags: java, memory

Currently I use the JPA to persist data in DB like derby via eclipse link.
Is there official option to store data in java in the memory and not in persistence layer?

Examples will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just user Derby [in-memory mode](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html):

Connection URL:

```
jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true
```

But remember that the database will not be persisted at all (which means that you will start with a blank database every time that you run your application). To make a in-memory database persistent you need to call:

```
SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a database with in memory mode. For this I prefer H2 (http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases)/